# Rails: use Jquery to change simple form input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails, been trying for hours to search for the answer but still no luck.
I created a "select all" button so that once it's clicked, regions should be automatically filled with all the region codes.
Thanks in advance for any help!

partial _form:

```
<div id  = "select_regions_form">
  <%= render partial: 'reports/regions_form', locals: { f: f, all_regions: @all_regions } %>
  <%= button_tag "Select All", :id => "select_all", :class => "btn btn-small btn-inverse", :type => "button" %>
  </br>
</div>
```

parial  _region_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id = "region_list" class="col-md-4">
    <%= f.input :regions, collection: all_regions, 
    label_method: :region_code, value_method: :id, input_html: { multiple: true }%>

  </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
(function($){
  "use strict";

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select_all").click(function() {
      $("input:regions").val(*all the region codes*);

    } );
  } );
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

**parial _region_form.html.erb:**

Add ID to the select input or use the ID already available which is automatically created by rails (FYI: you can inspect and see the ID in the browser).

Here, I am adding an ID `select_regions` for the select field.

```
<%= f.input :regions, collection: all_regions, 
    label_method: :region_code, value_method: :id, input_html: { multiple: true, id: 'select_regions' }%>
```

**javascript:**

Set the property `selected` to `true` for all options on click of select all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#select_all").click(function() {
    $('#select_regions option').prop('selected', true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi this still doesnt really do anything as I click the button

Comment: In which file you have the script. In separate JS file or in form partial?